Where to actually put the python module file for Pluggable Modules on a Docker Matrix-Synapse server?
Currently I've got a Matrix Synapse server running inside a docker container. I've mapped the /data directory to a directory on the server so I can edit the homeserver.yaml file.
Now, the documentation states that, in order to make a "Pluggable Module" usable, you need to define it thus in the homeserver.yaml config file:
modules:
  - module: my_super_module.MySuperClass

I've got a my_super_module.py residing in the /data directory next to the homeserver.yaml. However, upon starting the server the logs state that the my_super_module.py file could not be located.
The documentation is very sparse on that point. So, how do I register the module properly?
